# R fmatch for vectors?

Tags: r, match

I have the `fmatch` function working in a loop but I was wondering if it's possible to apply this functionality to the vector all once rather than looping through.

Here is the code running through the loop, which currently works.

```
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(fastmatch)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(RcppBDT)
##library(anytime)

## Load time zone data sheet
TZData  <- read_excel("TZDataFile.xlsx")
TZData <- as.data.table(TZData)
TZRange <- TZData[,1]
TZRange <- as.data.frame(TZRange)

##Bring in test data
TD  <- read_excel("Test dates.xlsx", col_types = c("text", "text"))
TD <- as.data.table(TD)

####Start Time Conversion Code####

## Define variables
Station <- TD[,1] ##Station
GMT <- TD[,2] ##Date/time stamp in GMT to be converted to local
z <- nrow(TD)+0
APLDateTime <- data.frame(RawLocal = double(), RawLocalDateTime = as.Date(character()))

for (i in 1:z) {
  STA <- as.character(Station[i,1]) ## Get Station
  APCode <- as.integer(fmatch(STA, TZRange[,1])) ## Match station on Time Zone Data sheet
```

When I try to just run

```
STA <- as.character(Station[,1]) ## Get Station
  APCode <- as.integer(fmatch(STA, TZRange[,1])) ## Match station on Time Zone Data sheet
```

I get `NA_integer_` for APCode.

Sample Data:

```
> STA
[1] "c(\"LHR\", \"PHL\", \"DFW\", \"PHX\", \"LAX\", \"BCN\")"

> head(TZRange,10)
   Code
1   369
2   04G
3   06A
4   06C
5   06N
6   09J
7   0A9
8   0G6
9   0G7
10  0P2
1183 DFW
2748 LHR
3809 PHL
```

I am looking for a result like

APCode = c(2748, 3809, 1183, etc.)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: could you please provide a sample of your data?

Comment: sample data added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!  I had to set both `STA` and `TZRange` `as.data.frame` then run the code `APCode <- fmatch(STA[,1], TZRange[,1])` and it worked perfectly.  I did first try the `na.omit` Antonis suggested, but it did not give me the list of indexes like I was looking for.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

First I assume you want STA to be a character vector. As I do not have your full data I will use the one provided and convert it

```
STA<-"c(\"LHR\", \"PHL\", \"DFW\", \"PHX\", \"LAX\", \"BCN\")"%>%substring(2)%>%str_replace_all("[[:punct:]]","")
> STA
[1] "LHR PHL DFW PHX LAX BCN"
```

Let me put an extra value so it finds a match to TZRange:

```
STA=c(STA,"04G")
> STA
[1] "LHR PHL DFW PHX LAX BCN" "04G"
```

For TZRange I have kept the 10 first values your provided

```
> TZRange
   code
1   369
2   04G
3   06A
4   06C
5   06N
6   09J
7   0A9
8   0G6
9   0G7
10  0P2
```

Now you can specify the index of TZRange where matches with STA are found

```
APCode <- na.omit(fmatch(STA,TZRange[,1]))[1]
> APCode
[1] 2
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate the assistance, but I got the same results.  You did have me take a better look at my `STA` variable and I realized I needed to get rid of the `as.character` and now  `STA = chr "LHR" "PHL" "DFW" ...`  I was hoping that would fix my issue, but it did not.  For some reason it is still coming back with `int NA` for `APCode`.

Comment: you run `na.omit(fmatch(STA,TZRange[,1]))[1]` and still get the same error?

Comment: This is weird have you included `STA=c(STA,"04G")` so STA has at least one common value with `TZRange[,1]` ? By the way you do not need the `as.integer` part of the code

Comment: Not sure why, but it had to do with needing both being set to `as.data.frame` before running the `fmatch`.  And I did omit the `as.integer` in the final code.  Thanks, again.